# How to convert dict value into readable CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

How to convert `dict` value into readable CSV file? I already tried to write it, but not success.

Original value:

```
[328900559584, 185455615753, 296889631456]
```

I want to make my file look like this:

```
328900559584
185455615753
296889631456
```

My code:

```
with open('cluster1.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in my_dict.items()]
```

Comment: Your original value is a list, not a dict.

Comment: how to convert?

Comment: How to convert what? You may want to look at the `csv` module, it's designed to write `csv` files.

Comment: Don't use `f.write` in a list comprehsion. You shouldn't​ mix side effects with a functional construct, it's bad style, and worse, it is inefficient in this case. That being said, I do not understand what your `dict` is.

Comment: Why would you want to convert?

Comment: how to make like that in my question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If he'd expanded it out into a for loop, wouldn't it be the same thing? (Stylistically, I do _personally_ prefer keeping side-effects out of map/reduce/comprehensions, but not for any concrete reasons.)

Comment: Your title says dictionary, your example is a list, and the error you report is a `numpy` error, indicating you actually have some `numpy.array`... What *exactly* are you working with?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Well, one important difference is that a list comprehension *creates a list* that wont be used, but it still allocates the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting that you're using a list instead of a dict:

```
my_lines = [328900559584, 185455615753, 296889631456]

with open('cluster1.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in my_lines:
        f.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: i got error message TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')

Comment: Forgot to add `str` conversion when switching my answer from using `print` to `f.write`. Sorry about that; should be fixed now! :)

Comment: That error doesn't make sense unless you are iterating over some `numpy` data structure and `line` is a something like a `np.array` the code above actually throws a *different* type error...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was just noticing that when running on my own machine . . . I'm guessing OP didn't provide the original code in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import os
list = [328900559584, 185455615753, 296889631456]
with open('cluster1.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write(str(n) + os.linesep) for n in list]
```

Using os.linesep is a good idea, because that will use the right line separator for your system ("\n" or "\n\r" etc).